# Actualizar entrada sqlite desde tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

Tengo una aplicación para control de stock en la que puedo añadir entrada a la DB sin problemas, el problema viene cuando intento modificar los datos de una entrada, me devuelve el error:

```
File "inventario.py", line 153, in sql_query
    cursor.execute(query, datos)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Esta es la función para agregar una entrada:

```
def p1_add(self):
        datos = (self.p1_Entry_modelo.get(), self.p1_Entry_formato.get(), self.p1_Entry_capacidad.get(), self.p1_Entry_cantidad.get())

        query = "INSERT INTO discos_duros (modelo, formato, capacidad, cantidad) VALUEs (?, ?, ?, ?)"
        sql_query(query, datos)

        query = "SELECT modelo, formato, capacidad, cantidad FROM discos_duros"
        self.load_data(query)
```

Esta es la función para modificar la entrada:

```
def p1_mod(self):
        datos = (self.p1_Entry_cantidad.get(), self.p1_Entry_modelo.get(), self.p1_Entry_formato.get(), self.p1_Entry_capacidad.get())

        query = "UPDATE discos_duros SET cantidad=? WHERE modelo=? AND formato=? AND capacidad=? (?, ?, ?, ?)"
        sql_query(query, datos)

        query = "SELECT modelo, formato, capacidad, cantidad FROM discos_duros"
        self.load_data(query)
```

Y esta la función que trabaja con la DB:

```
def sql_query(query,datos=""):
    con = sqlite3.connect("inventario.db")
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query, datos)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    con.commit()
    cursor.close()
    con.close()

    return records
```

Comment: solo debes quitar la ultima parte `capacidad=? (?, ?, ?, ?)` debe quedar asi `capacidad=?` dado que ya estas enviando los parametros indicados por el simbolo `?` los ultimos es un error solo se usa en insert...

Comment: Solucionado, muchas gracias.